# Deploying using Vercel shows the raw code of index.js instead of rendering it

Tags: deployment, render, mern, vercel

I'm trying to deploy my web application (React + NodeJS) to the internet.
For some reason, after deploying, it just shows me the raw code of index.js instead of showing the rendered web application :
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2BYG.png)

I did some research online, and all I could find was to add a vercel.json file, which didn't work.
My project is on github, at :
https://github.com/barakdaniel1/recipe_book-project/tree/main

Thank you in advance for any help, been stuck on this for hours.